# How to covert JavaScript string to executable code in node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6

I have saved query in database. I can get query as a string.

```
INSERT INTO alertsV SET Instance_ID = ${body.add.Instance_ID}
```

But `${body.add.Instance_ID}` is not replacing with value.

expected result should be `INSERT INTO alertsV SET Instance_ID = 1234`

I am using nodejs. Please help me how to fix this. Here is the function.

```
  saveFormData: async function (req, res) {
     let form_id = parseInt(req.body.form_id);
     let body = req.body.form_data;
     let saveQuery = await sails.orientDb.command('select actions.save as 
     saveQuery from form where form_id=' + form_id).one();

     saveQuery = saveQuery.saveQuery; // i can get string here 'INSERT INTO alertsV SET Instance_ID = ${body.add.Instance_ID}'
     let result = await sails.orientDb.command(saveQuery).one();
     return res.json(result);
  }
```

Comment: You are looking for a templating engine, not `eval`. Btw it's a really bad idea to store SQL commands in your database.

Comment: i tried with INSERT INTO alertsV SET Instance_ID = '+ body.add.Instance_ID + ' . Does not work @Bergi .

Comment: Why not just write ``const result = await sails.orientDb.command(`INSERT INTO alertsV SET Instance_ID = ${body.add.Instance_ID}`).one();``. Forget about the `safeQuery` thing that is loaded from a database.

Comment: why did you negative vote for this? do you have the solution for this?  It is necessary to store sql statement in db.

Comment: @Bergi you did not get the question. These query will be saved by the user. It's a very dynamic and internal platform. Do you have solutions or not ?

Comment: What happens if a disgruntled employee decides to save `DELETE alertsV;` as a query instead? This approach is extremely dangerous because it relies on everyone interacting with your system to know exactly what they are doing and have no malicious intentions.

Comment: @PritamParua Ok, then you'll probably be happy to use `eval`, as your application can't get much more insecure anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can wrap a string in the template literal backticks and pass it to `eval` to run string interpolation:

```
saveQuery = eval('`' + saveQuery.saveQuery + '`');
```

```js
const a = 10;
const str = 'test ${a} test';

console.log(eval('`' + str + '`'));

/*
if it's required to wrap the interpolated value into a quotes, 
you can do that by wrapping the embedded expression, prior to interpolation:
*/
console.log(eval('`' + str.replace(/(\${.*})/, '\'$1\'') + '`'));
```

Comment: perfect .. Thanks @antonku

Comment: But problem is i am getting  INSERT INTO alertsV SET Instance_ID = 1234fef . I need INSERT INTO alertsV SET Instance_ID = '1234fef' .

Comment: @PritamParua Hi, thanks for accepting the answer. Regarding quotes enclosing the interpolated value - this can be done by enclosing the embedded expression into quotes (prior to interpolation). I have updated the answer with an example.